# BLoC different states for updating different widgets

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm using bloc for the first time and I think I do something wrong. I have an ListView with some Entries, loaded via REST-Api:

Event:

- `LoadData`

States:

- `Uninitialized`
- `Loading`
- `NoData`
- `Loaded(entries)`

Then I want to add the `DeleteEntry(entryId)` Event. Should the Event yield a Loaded-State with the new List of entries? Then, how to represent an error with deleting the entry?

Is it maybe better to have ListStates (`Uninitialized`, `Loading`, `NoData`, `Loaded`) and EntryStates (`EntryDeleted`, `EntryNotDeleted`). Then the BlocBuilder could only affect on ListStates and the entryStates are handled seperatly?

Or should I have seperate Blocs here?

Comment: If I get your usecase right, it's better to just stick with the current states. Because EntryDeleted and EntryNotDeletd will be no different with Loaded after all. It's just the (entries) which changes element. Also rather than naming the state NoData, I think it's better to name it NotLoaded, because when the request is successful but the return data is indeed an empty list, you would still want to yield Loaded with empty list instead of NoData

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But how you would handle, that the deletion didn't work? 
 
The Loaded-State returns 5 entries. The user delete two of them, the api responds, that one delete request was successful, the other failed. As you recommend, the BLoC returns a Loaded-State after Delete-Event with 4 elements left. How to transport the information, that something didn't work?

Comment: I don't know how you handle the backend but you could add one more field in the Loaded state like String errorMessage. Then in the Widget tree you could use BlocListener if (state is Loaded && state.entry.errorMessage != null) print('${state.entry.errorMessage}');